# Организация настроек параметров и их обработка в классе c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос наверное звучит очень странно. Я новичок не судите строго!

Я ни как не могу додуматься как мне организовать настройки каких то так сказать что ли элементов.

Есть список элементов:
element1, element2, element3.
Их  пользователь может выбрать с помощи checkBox`а.
И у  каждого элемента должны быть настройки (разные) которые пользователь может выбрать.

| element1 | element2 | element3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| настройка: true,false | настройка: text | настройка: true,false |
| настройка2: true,false | настройка2: text | настройка2: true,false |
| настройка3: text | настройка3: text | настройка3: true,false |

Примерно так.
Настройки могут быть разные.

Пользователь должен выбрать  существующие элементы и настроить их.
И потом программно я должен как то передать все  элементы с настройками и обрабатывать их.
Я не знаю глупо ли это или что то сложное, но мне  нужно что бы пользователь выбрал элемент с настройками и я как то их обрабатывал.

Я думал, создать массив с классами, в этих классах название элемента и их настройки.
И передавать этот массив классов в другой класс или же хранить его там изначально, что бы тот обрабатывал элементы. Может это ультра глупо, но я представить не могу как по другому.

**Windows Form c#**

Comment: А можете чуть подробнее рассказать, что скрывается за этими настройками? У меня, конечно, есть картина, как это можно сделать, но информации о данных настройках не хватает. element1 - раздел с определёнными настройками? Может скриншот программы приложить сможете? Станет гораздо легче

Comment: Если вы сохранить настройки - есть тонна вариантов. Например, ini-файлы или json. Если передавать куда-то в качестве параметра, то определённо лучше создать класс и в нём описать свойства, конструкторы и тд. В дальнейшем передавать именно его

Comment: Если вы не понимаете, как извлечь данные, то тоже можно несколькими путями - привязка данных (проще всего это делать через wpf), либо обращение к конкретному checkbox и вызов свойства checked. Конечно, можно создать обработку свойств реализовав интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, но это чуть сложнее будет

Comment: @Frehzy спасибо за ответ! Любая помощь мне очень поможет.
У меня программа, бот который берет информацию на сайте. Делает запрос средствами .net и проверяет страницу и в ней элементы.
Элемент - название сайта, а настройки - какую информацию от туда брать.
Мне нужно что бы пользователь выбрал например 2 сайта, настроил что ему нужно брать, и запустить программу.

У меня есть класс, который принимает некоторые параметры и хотелось бы настройки пользователя.
Он парсит страницу в зависимости от `Массив((сайт | настройки))` и сохраняет результат. Я не знаю как грамотно реализовать это.

Comment: @Frehzy спасибо за наводку json, ini файлы. Если вы можете то подскажите где можно почитать про это. 
Я думаю в настройках должно быть: `сайт - ссылка`, `что искать - селектор` (или еще что то) и так далее.
Но я думаю что то еще добавить. 
Не знаю как мне добавлять в зависимости какой сайт нажал, и как добавлять настройки к этому сайту.
Дизайн программы вовсе даже нет, а код вот, только парсит страницу в конкретном классе и в будущем должен сохранять в переменные найденный результат.

Comment: @Frehzy, я не правильно написал выше. Элементы на сайте это цифры, или еще что то. А элемент настроек это сайт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136376/discussion-between-frehzy-and-komend).